# How to make the page link take the page title

Tags: hyperlink

How do I make make Hyperlinks more readable? For example, instead of displaying this:

http://www.sharmsmile.com/show.php?bsort=sharm&subsort=CULTURAL%20TOURS&page=CAIRO%20BY%20PLANE&trip=show

I would rather it just be this: http://www.sharmsmile.com/cairobyplane